# want to change a button text depending on the value from the script

Tags: python, html, webiopi

Hi i got some problem with my webiopi html and script i cant change the button state depending on the value in the script.py im getting this error in chrome console

this is when it auto refresh the button.

```
POST http://192.168.0.108:8000/macros/get_DoorStatus/0 404 (get_DoorStatus Not Found)
```

And when i press it i get.

```
Uncaught TypeError: ((n.event.special[e.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || e.handler).apply is not a function
```

this is the index.html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content = "height = device-height, width = 420, user-scalable = no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>WebIOPi | Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/webiopi.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    webiopi().ready(function() {
        var content, button;
        content = $("#content");

        // create a button which call HelloWorld with "User,Name" argument
        button = webiopi().createMacroButton("macro", "On", "HelloWorld");
        content.append(button); // append button to content div

        // the previous button will always call HelloWorld with "User,Name" argument
        // you can also create a simple button with your own function 
        button = webiopi().createMacroButton("macro2", "Off", "HelloWorld2");
        content.append(button); // append button to content div

                // create a button which call function to get SwitchStatus from script.py (GPIO 27) 
                button = webiopi().createButton("macro3", "Door", "callMacro_get_DoorStatus");
                content.append(button); // append button to content div

    });



    //webiopi().refreshGPIO(true);

    window.onload = function(){
        callMacro_get_DoorStatus()
        }
               setInterval ("callMacro_get_DoorStatus()", 5000);{
        }

    function callMacro() {
        // call HelloWorld(args)
        webiopi().callMacro("HelloWorld()");
    }

        function callMacro() {
        // call HelloWorld2(args)
        webiopi().callMacro("HelloWorld2()");
    }


        function callMacro_get_DoorStatus(){
                   var args = [0]
                  //Get data form script.py and return it with Callback
        webiopi().callMacro("get_DoorStatus", args, macro_get_DoorStatus_Callback);}

        function macro_get_DoorStatus_Callback(macro, args, data){
                p0 = data.split(" ")[0];
                if (p0==1){
                webiopi().setClass("macro3", "Open");
                webiopi().setLabel("macro3", "Door Open");}
                else{
                webiopi().setClass("macro3", "Closed");
                webiopi().setLabel("macro3", "Door Closed");}
                }

    </script>


</head>
<body>
        <h1 align="center">Switch 1</h1>
    <div id="content" align="center"></div>
        <style type="text/css">
        button {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            width: 160px;
            height: 45px;
            font-size: 24pt;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: black;
        }

</body>
</html>
```

here is the script.py code

```
# Imports
import webiopi
import time
import urllib.request
import requests

# Enable debug output
webiopi.setDebug()

# Retrieve GPIO lib
GPIO = webiopi.GPIO

SWITCH = 21
SERVO  = 23
LED0   = 24
LED1   = 25

# Called by WebIOPi at script loading
def setup():
    webiopi.debug("Script with macros - Setup")
    # Setup GPIOs
    GPIO.setFunction(SWITCH, GPIO.IN)
    #GPIO.setFunction(SERVO, GPIO.PWM)
    #GPIO.setFunction(LED0, GPIO.PWM)
    #GPIO.setFunction(LED1, GPIO.OUT)

    #GPIO.pwmWrite(LED0, 0.5)        # set to 50% ratio
    #GPIO.pwmWriteAngle(SERVO, 0)    # set to 0 (neutral)
    #GPIO.digitalWrite(LED1, GPIO.HIGH)



# Looped by WebIOPi
def loop():
    # Toggle LED each 5 seconds
    #value = not GPIO.digitalRead(LED1)
    #GPIO.digitalWrite(LED1, value)
    webiopi.sleep(5)        

# Called by WebIOPi at server shutdown
def destroy():
    webiopi.debug("Script with macros - Destroy")
    # Reset GPIO functions
    #GPIO.setFunction(SWITCH, GPIO.IN)
    #GPIO.setFunction(SERVO, GPIO.IN)
    #GPIO.setFunction(LED0, GPIO.IN)
    #GPIO.setFunction(LED1, GPIO.IN)
    #gpio0 = webiopi.deviceInstance("gpio0")
    #gpio0.digitalWrite(0, 1)

# A macro which says hello
@webiopi.macro
def HelloWorld():
    urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.0.200:9090/?dW5pdDFPTg==").read()

# A macro without args which return nothing
@webiopi.macro
def HelloWorld2():
    urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.0.200:9090/?dW5pdDFPRkY=").read()

@webiopi.macro
def get_DoorStatus(arg0):
    x = urllib.request.urlopen('http://192.168.0.200:9090/')
    if 'Switch1Off' in x.read():
    print (p0)
    return "%d" % p0 # returns "0" or "1"
```

Comment: Never mind got it to work.